# Transition issue CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I want to setup a animation for the backdrop-filter property. When I use plain CSS it works but when I toggle the class in JS it doesn't work anymore.

I have tried to isolate the problem but I don't understand how to solve it.

MENU HTML

```html
            <nav id="main-menu">
                <ul>
                    <a href="http://localhost/jorime/">
                        <li>Work</li>
                    </a>
                    <!-- <a href="services"><li>Services</li></a> -->
                    <a href="#">
                        <li id="contact-link">Contact</li>
                    </a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

CONTACT HTML

```html
        <section id="contact-wrapper" class="hide">
            <section id="contact-content">
                <section id="contact-close-button">
                    <button>X</button>
                </section>
                <section id="contact-header">
                    <h2>Contact</h2>
                    <p class="importent">Feel free to leave a message!</p>
                </section>
                <section id="contact-body">
                    <form action="">
                        <input type="text" class="contact-form-field" id="contact-form-name"
                            placeholder="Enter your name" />
                        <input type="text" class="contact-form-field" id="contact-form-email"
                            placeholder="Enter your email" />
                        <textarea class="contact-form-field" rows="10" id="contact-form-message"
                            placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
                        <section class="flex-right">
                            <input id="contact-form-submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
                        </section>
                    </form>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
```

CSS

```css
        #contact-wrapper{
            display: block;
            backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .75);
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            transition: backdrop-filter 1.5s;
        }

        #contact-wrapper.hide{
            display: none;
            backdrop-filter: blur(0px);
            transition: backdrop-filter 1.5s;
        }
```

JS

```js
function toggleClass(elementId, cssClass){
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.classList.toggle(cssClass);
}

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("contact-link").addEventListener("click", function(){
        toggleClass("contact-wrapper", "hide");
    });

    document.getElementById("contact-close-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
        toggleClass("contact-wrapper", "hide");
    });
}
```

I want the backdrop transition working.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: where is your contact-link button

Comment: This is in the menu, <li id="contact-link">Contact</li>

Comment: Can you please put it into your code?

Comment: Of course. I added the code.

It shows the contact form so I think the link is good. I have tried to remove the A tag but the transition doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer:

You can't animate the `Display` property.

You can simulate this by using other properties like `opacity`, `visibility`, and adjusting `height` and/or `width`. Often used is setting the `opacity` and `height` to `0`. This causes a similar effect to `display: none` since it causes the element to effectively remove the space it takes up in the DOM while rendering it invisible. **Note** You may also need to set `padding`, `width`, and `margin` to `0` if you truly want it to be as minimally existent in the DOM as possible.

You also can't transition just *one* property like `backdrop-filter` when some other altered property causes the element to be invisible. **why?** because it's interpreted by the Browser as "immediately make this element **invisible** while *transitioning* the other properties*." Basically it makes the whole operation pointless.

The syntax in your case to add multiple properties to transition is something like this:

```
 transition: prop time, prop time, prop time;
```

If all altered properties are to be transitioned you can also just use:

```
 transition: all 1.5s;
```

---

### Example:

**NOTE** I updated with your menu code. I don't know where the menu is located, but to get it work with the demo code I had to alter the z-index depending on if `hide` was applied. This is because of the `fixed` top-left nature of the `contact-wrapper`. Depending on your markup you may not need to alter this or may need to alter it differently.

```js
function toggleClass(elementId, cssClass){
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.classList.toggle(cssClass);
}

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("contact-link").addEventListener("click", function(){
        toggleClass("contact-wrapper", "hide");
    });

    document.getElementById("contact-close-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
        toggleClass("contact-wrapper", "hide");
    });
}
```

```css
#contact-wrapper{
            display: block;
            opacity: 1;
            backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .75);
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 1;
            transition: opacity 1.5s, margin 1.5s, padding 1.5s, height 1.5s, backdrop-filter 1.5s;
        }

        #contact-wrapper.hide{
            opacity: 0;
            height: 0;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            z-index: -1;
            backdrop-filter: blur(0px);
        }
```

```html
<nav id="main-menu">
                <ul>
                    <a href="http://localhost/jorime/">
                        <li>Work</li>
                    </a>
                    <!-- <a href="services"><li>Services</li></a> -->
                    <a href="#">
                        <li id="contact-link">Contact</li>
                    </a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
<section id="contact-wrapper" class="hide">
            <section id="contact-content">
                <section id="contact-close-button">
                    <button>X</button>
                </section>
                <section id="contact-header">
                    <h2>Contact</h2>
                    <p class="importent">Feel free to leave a message!</p>
                </section>
                <section id="contact-body">
                    <form action="">
                        <input type="text" class="contact-form-field" id="contact-form-name"
                            placeholder="Enter your name" />
                        <input type="text" class="contact-form-field" id="contact-form-email"
                            placeholder="Enter your email" />
                        <textarea class="contact-form-field" rows="10" id="contact-form-message"
                            placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
                        <section class="flex-right">
                            <input id="contact-form-submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
                        </section>
                    </form>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
```

Comment: When I open the contact form it's animates. But when I close it, it disapears immediately. I overwrite my css with yours.

Comment: @jorime if you copied it than it shouldn't. do you still have `display: none` anywhere?

Comment: @Jorime I have no idea what you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry.

I have a page with clickable content and static text. The contact form must be open in the same page with full height and width of the screen. So there is other things on the page.

When you open the contact form the transitions works fine. But when you close the contact form. The z-index of the contact section is lower than the z-index of the text and images. So the backdrop filters falls below the other content so you don't see the blur to clear effect.

Comment: I got it working, I had to add: z-index 1.5s 0s to the transition.

Comment: I see, nice job

Comment: Thanks for the help!